# TCPDF save file with 755 permission

Tags: php, permissions, phpmailer, cpanel, tcpdf

I am trying to save a PDF using `TCPDF` and then attach it to `PHPMailer`. Everything goes well until the attachment process. The PDF is saved with 0644 permissions. The error I'm getting is
`Could not access file: /path_to_file/file.pdf`

The way I'm creating the pdf is

```
$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'F');
```

The way I'm adding an attachment is

```
if(file_exists('/path_to_file/file.pdf')) {
   $mail->AddAttachment('/path_to_file/file.pdf', $name = 'PDF',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
}
```

The email is sent but obviously there's no attachment since I'm getting the error in logs. Is there any way to save the PDF with 0755 permissions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

0755 permissions won’t help, and would be inappropriate and potentially dangerous. PDF files do not need to be marked as executable for them to be readable. I would double check your paths (display absolute paths - you’re relying on relative paths and your cwd may not be what you think) and the permissions of enclosing folders.

Comment: I thought of permissions as a last resort. I even used `file_exists` and it passes. I even hardcoded the path.

Comment: Are you using the same hard-coded absolute path in the `Output` call? You don't need to wrap `addAttachment` in a `file_exists` call; it already does that for you internally, so check its return value.

Comment: BTW you don't have to output to a file and then reload it - you can output to a string in memory and then attach that directly (see `addStringAttachment`). That's more efficient if the generated PDF is not too big.